# All in all it's just, uh, another trick in code golf

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

The purpose of this challenge is to produce an ASCII version of the cover of [this great album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wall) by the rock band Pink Floyd.

The brick junctions are made of characters `_` and `|`. Bricks have width 7 and height 2 characters, excluding junctions. So the basic unit, including the junctions, is:

```
_________
|       |
|       |
_________
```

Each row of bricks is **offset by half a brick width** (4 chars) with respect to the previous row:

```
________________________________________
  |       |       |       |       |     
  |       |       |       |       |     
________________________________________
      |       |       |       |       | 
      |       |       |       |       | 
________________________________________
  |       |       |       |       |     
  |       |       |       |       |
```

The wall is **parameterized** as follows. All parameters are measured in chars including junctions:

1. **Horizontal offset** of first row, `F`. This is the distance between the left margin and the first vertical junction of the upmost row. (Remember also the half-brick relative offset between rows). Its possible values are `0`, `1`, ..., `7`.
2. Total **width**, `W`. This includes junctions. Its value is a positive integer.
3. Total **height**, `H`. This includes junctions. Its value is a positive integer.

The top of the wall always coincides with the top of a row. The bottom may be ragged (if the total height is not a multiple of `3`). For example, here's the output for `6`, `44`, `11`:

```
____________________________________________
      |       |       |       |       |     
      |       |       |       |       |     
____________________________________________
  |       |       |       |       |       |     
  |       |       |       |       |       |     
____________________________________________
      |       |       |       |       |     
      |       |       |       |       |     
____________________________________________
  |       |       |       |       |       |
```

and a visual explanation of parameters:

```
          F=6
         ......   
     .   ____________________________________________
     .         |       |       |       |       |    
     .         |       |       |       |       |     
     .   ____________________________________________
     .     |       |       |       |       |       | 
H=11 .     |       |       |       |       |       |      
     .   ____________________________________________
     .         |       |       |       |       |     
     .         |       |       |       |       |     
     .   ____________________________________________
     .     |       |       |       |       |       |      

         ............................................
                             W=44
```

### Additional rules

You may provide a program or a function.

Input format is flexible as usual. Output may be through STDOUT or an argument returned by a function. In this case it may be a string with newlines or an array of strings.

Trailing spaces or newlines are allowed.

Shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

Inputs are in the order given above, that is: horizontal offset of first row, total width, total height.

```
6, 44, 11:
____________________________________________
      |       |       |       |       |     
      |       |       |       |       |     
____________________________________________
  |       |       |       |       |       | 
  |       |       |       |       |       | 
____________________________________________
      |       |       |       |       |     
      |       |       |       |       |     
____________________________________________
  |       |       |       |       |       |     


2, 20, 10:
____________________
  |       |       | 
  |       |       | 
____________________
      |       |     
      |       |     
____________________
  |       |       | 
  |       |       | 
____________________


1, 1, 1:
_


1, 2, 3:
__
 |
 |


3, 80, 21:
________________________________________________________________________________
   |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |    
   |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |    
________________________________________________________________________________
       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
________________________________________________________________________________
   |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |    
   |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |    
________________________________________________________________________________
       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
________________________________________________________________________________
   |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |    
   |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |    
________________________________________________________________________________
       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
________________________________________________________________________________
   |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |    
   |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
```

Comment: You got me with the clickbait in the hnq

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Sounds about right

Comment: Thank you for matching the number of syllables in the lyrics... you wouldn't believe how many people try to spin-off a song and get the syllabification wrong, it drives me nuts!

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Haha, thanks! The title was an important part of this challenge

Comment: Nice Challenge! Could I suggest a title update, tho? It can be a bit more concise as "All in all it's just another trick in the code"

Comment: @AJFaraday Thanks! I like your proposal too, but I've grown fond of the current title :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Fair play, good challenge, tho. It's really taking off

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>43</s> 27 bytes

I ***need*** to golf it heavily... the score is too shameful.

```
AQVE<*H?%N3X*8d+G*4/N3\|\_H
```

[Try it online already.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=AQVE%3C%2aH%3F%25N3X%2a8d%2BG%2a4%2FN3%5C%7C%5C_H&input=6%2C44%0A11&debug=0)

#### Input format

```
6,44
11
```

#### Output format

```
____________________________________________
      |       |       |       |       |     
      |       |       |       |       |     
____________________________________________
  |       |       |       |       |       | 
  |       |       |       |       |       | 
____________________________________________
      |       |       |       |       |     
      |       |       |       |       |     
____________________________________________
  |       |       |       |       |       |
```

### Explanation

```
AQVE<*H?%N3X*8d+G*4/N3\|\_H   First two inputs as list in Q,
                              third input as E.

AQ                            Assign G to the first item in Q
                              and H to the second item in Q.
  VE                          For N from 0 to E-1:
                   /N3            N floor-div 3.
                                    if N gives a remainder of 3 or 4 or 5
                                    when divided by 6, this will be odd;
                                    otherwise, this will be even.
                 *4               Multiply by 4.
                                    if the above is odd, this will leave
                                    a remainder of 4 when divided by 8;
                                    otherwise, the remainder would be 0.
               +G                 Add G (as an offset).
           X*8d       \|          In the string "        " (*8d),
                                  replace (X) the character with the
                                  index above with "|" (modular indexing,
                                  hence the manipulation above).
       ?%N3             \_        If N%3 is non-zero, use the above;
                                  otherwise, use "_".
     *H                           The above repeated H times.
    <                     H       Take the first H characters of above.
                                  Implicitly print with newline.
```

Comment: looks like you win

Answer (score 30):

## C, <strike>86</strike> <strike>85</strike> <strike>83</strike> 82 bytes

3 bytes saved thanks to Lynn.
1 byte saved thanks to charlie.

```c
i;f(o,w,h){++w;for(i=0;++i<w*h;)putchar(i%w?i/w%3?i%w+i/w/3*4+~o&7?32:124:95:10);}
```

Comment: `for(i=0;++i<w*h;)` or if `i` is made local (param trick): `for(;++i<w*h;)`

Comment: replace `i;` by `i=1;` and save one more byte in the for loop.

Comment: `for(i=1;i<w*h;++i)` -> `for(i=0;++i<w*h;)` saves 1

Comment: @xryl669 That's not valid, functions must be reusable.

Comment: @Yay295 I credited charlie with that, since he posted it 7 hours earlier.

Comment: Suggest `for(i=!++w` instead of `++w;for(i=0`

Answer (score 26):

## C, 92 bytes

```c
b(f,w,h,y,x){for(y=0;y<h;y++,puts(""))for(x=0;x<w;x++)putchar(y%3?(x+y/3*4-f)%8?32:124:95);}
```

Invoke as `b(F, W, H)`.

Comment: Only 92 bytes in C? That's incredible.

Comment: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9JI02nXCdDp1KnQrM6Lb9Io9LWwLrSJkOr3Fpbu1K1vKamoLSkWENJSVMTyEjOSASq0C9XNbYHymkDWfrGWia6aWrm9sZGVoZGJlaWpprWtf9zEzPzNDSrkzTMdExMdAwNQWIA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 13):

## Perl, 63 bytes

```perl
#!perl -nl
$y+=print+map$y%3?$_++-$`&7?$":'|':_,($y%6&4)x$&for/ \d+/..$'
```

Counting the shebang as 2, input is taken from stdin, whitespace separated.

**Sample Usage**

```perl
$ echo 2 20 10 | perl bricks.pl
____________________
  |       |       |
  |       |       |
____________________
      |       |
      |       |
____________________
  |       |       |
  |       |       |
____________________
```

Answer (score 11):

### Haskell, 83 bytes

```
q s="_":[s,s]
(f!w)h=take h$cycle$take w.drop(7-f).cycle<$>q"       |"++q"   |    "
```

This defines a ternary infix function `!` which returns a list of strings. Usage example:

```
*Main> putStrLn $ unlines $ (3!14) 7
______________
   |       |  
   |       |  
______________
       |      
       |      
______________
```

How it works:

```
            q"       |"++q"   |    "  -- build a list of 6 strings
                                      --   1:     "_"
                                      --   2:     "       |"
                                      --   3:     "       |"
                                      --   4:     "_"
                                      --   5:     "   |    "
                                      --   6:     "   |    "
         <$>                          -- for each of the strings
     take w.drop(7-f).cycle           -- repeat infinitely, drop the first 7-f chars
                                      --    and take the next w chars
  cycle                               -- infinitely repeat the resulting list
take h                                -- and take the first h elements
```

Comment: Answers like this make me want to learn this language.

Comment: I thought of Haskell when reading the problem description.  "Repeat infinitely" is a really neat feature to have.

Answer (score 10):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>96</s> 95 bytes

```js
g=
(f,w,h)=>[...Array(h)].map((_,i)=>(i%3?`       |`:`_`).repeat(w+7).substr(f^7^i%6&4,w)).join`
`
;
```

```html
<div onchange=o.textContent=g(f.value,w.value,+h.value)><input id=f type=number min=0 max=7 placeholder=Offset><input id=w type=number min=0 placeholder=Width><input id=h type=number min=0 placeholder=Height></div><pre id=o>
```

Explanation: Creates a string of either the repeating 7 spaces plus `|` pattern or just repeated `_`s, but at least long enough to be able to extract the `w` characters required for each row. The first three rows start at position `f^7` and then the next three rows start at position `f^3`, so I achieve this by <s>toggling bit 2 of `f` on every third row</s> using the opposite bit 2 on the last two rows of each block of 6 for a saving of 1 byte.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, <s>93</s> 88 bytes

<s>2nd indentation level is tab</s> Saving some bytes thanks to Leaky Nun and some own modifications, also now correct offset:

```python
def f(F,W,H):
 for h in range(H):print["_"*W,((("|"+7*" ")*W)[8-F+h%6/3*4:])[:W]][h%3>0]
```

previous code:

```python
def f(F,W,H,x="|"+7*" "):
 for h in range(H):
    print ["_"*W,(x[F+4*(h%6>3):]+x*W)[:W]][h%3>0]
```

Same length as unnamed lambda:

```python
lambda F,W,H,x="|"+7*" ":"\n".join(["_"*W,(x[F+4*(h%6>3):]+x*W)[:W]][h%3>0]for h in range(H))
```

Comment: `F,W,H=input()`

Comment: remove the whitespace after `print`

Comment: use `h/3%2*4` or `h%6/3*4` instead of `4*(h%6>3)`

Comment: You don't need the second indentation level. Just put the `print` statement at the same line as the `for` statement

Comment: `"|       "` is shorter than `("|"+7*" ")` if I count correctly

Comment: I insist that it is shorter to use `F,W,H=input()`

Comment: I used variations of the same formulas in my QBasic answer (before peeking, of course).  The rest of the logic is pretty different, though.  Maybe some of the suggestions to optimize this answer will translate to mine.

Comment: `((7*" "+"|")*W)[F^7^h%6&4:]` saves you 2 bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## MATL, <s>42</s> <s>36</s> 33 bytes

```
:-Q'_ | |'[DClCl]Y"8et4YShwi:3$)!
```

Input format is: `nCols`, `offset`, `nRows`

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Oi1RJ18gfCB8J1tEQ2xDbF1ZIjhldDRZU2h3aTozJCkh&input=NDQKNgoxMQ)

The approach here is that we setup a "template" which we then index into by using the row indices (`[1 2 ... nRows]`) and column indices  shifted by the first input (`[1 2 ... nCols] - shift`). Thanks to MATL's modular indexing, it will automatically result in a tiled output. As a side-note, to save some space, technically I work with a transposed version of the template and then just take a transpose (`!`) at the end.

The template is this:

```
________
       |
       |
________
  |     
  |
```

Comment: Nice use of run-length coding to generate the pattern

Answer (score 6):

## QBasic, <s>121</s> 109 bytes

### (Tested on QB64)

Thanks to @DLosc for golfing my `IF` statement with a mathematical equivalent.  That was worth 12 bytes.

### General Method:

Loop through each cell one at a time and determine whether it should be a `_`,  , or `|` depending on its location.  `MOD` statements and boolean logic are used to determine brick boundaries and how much to stagger the bricks.

### Code:

```
INPUT F,W,H
FOR y=0TO H-1:FOR x=0TO W-1
?CHR$((y MOD 3>0)*(((x-(y MOD 6>3)*4)MOD 8=F)*92+63)+95);
NEXT:?:NEXT
```

### Usage Note:

QBasic expects input to be numbers separated by commas.

Comment: Using math instead of `IF`/`THEN` adds even more parentheses but saves 12 bytes: `?CHR$((y MOD 3>0)*(((x-(y MOD 6>3)*4)MOD 8=F)*92+63)+95);`

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  In the back of my head I had considered exploring math, but didn't.  I did something sort of similar to this to color an image in in a [recent submission](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85477/56253), but the implementation I used didn't have a MOD operator.

Answer (score 5):

## Java, <s>149</s>, <s>147</s>, <s>146</s>, 143 bytes

Golfed:

```java
String f(int o,int w,int h){String s="";for(int y=0,x;y<h;++y){for(x=0;x<w;++x){s+=y%3>0?(x-o+(y-1)/3%2*4)%8==0?'|':' ':'_';}s+='\n';}return s;}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
public class AllInAllItsJustUhAnotherTrickInCodeGolf {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int offset = 6;
    int width = 44;
    int height = 11;
    System.out.println(new AllInAllItsJustUhAnotherTrickInCodeGolf()
        .f(offset, width, height));
  }

  // Begin golf
  String f(int o, int w, int h) {
    String s = "";
    for (int y = 0, x; y < h; ++y) {
      for (x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
        s += y % 3 > 0 ? (x - o + (y - 1) / 3 % 2 * 4) % 8 == 0 ? '|' : ' ' : '_';
      }
      s += '\n';
    }
    return s;
  }
  // End golf

}
```

Comment: Maybe you could switch the order of the ternary by comparing to `> 0` which could save two characters. And of course you can combine the declarations to `int y=0,x`.

Comment: As being said by *Frozn*, you can remove `int ` before the `x` and use `int y=0,x` in the first for-loop instead to save 2 bytes. Also, currently your can change `y%3==0` to `y%3<1`. (This isn't possible for `...%8==0` to `...&8<1` though, since your operation could return a negative number.)

Comment: Done and done. You are correct, that second modulo can return negative and it did during debugging when I originally wrote this function.

Comment: Not sure how we missed this, but you can remove the spaces at your parameters for -2 bytes.. Alternatively, using `int...o` as parameter and changing `w` to `o[1]`, `h` to `o[2]` and `o` to `o[0]` is -3 bytes instead.

Answer (score 4):

## Julia: <s>150</s> <s>128</s> <s>116</s> <s>108</s> 107 bytes

```
# in codegolf.jl
r=repmat;b=r([' '],6,8);b[[1,4],:]='_';b[[2,3,23,24]]='|';b=r(b,h,w)[1:h,o+=1:o+w];b[:,end]=10;print(b'...)
```

to run with arguments: `julia -e 'o=2;h=18;w=40;include("codegolf.jl")'`

If you feel calling from bash is cheating and you want a function inside the interpreter, then the function version is 117 bytes :)

```
f(o,h,w)=(r=repmat;b=r([' '],6,8);b[[1,4],:]='_';b[[2,3,23,24]]='|';b=r(b,h,w)[1:h,o+=1:o+w];b[:,end]=10;print(b'...))
```

[demo](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=ZihvLGgsdyk9KGI9MzIqb25lcyhJbnQzMiw2LDgpO2JbWzEsNF0sOl09OTU7YltbMiwzLDIzLDI0XV09MTI0O2I9cmVwbWF0KGIsaCx3KVsxOmgsbysxOm8rdysxXTtiWzosZW5kXT0xMDtwcmludChyZWludGVycHJldChDaGFyLGInKS4uLikpCmYoMiwgMTgsNDAp&input=)

(Thanks, @glen-o for the extra byte-saving tip!)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice to see you also here!

Comment: Note that inputs should be taken explicitly, i.e. you need some kind of input statement for those three variables. Or you can use a function that takes them as arguments and outputs or displays the result. When you are done, you may want to post an online demo using [Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/)

Comment: Also, it appears [you have interpreted `h` and `w` in bricks, not in chars](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=bz0yOyB3PTEwOyBoPTEyOwpDPWNpcmNzaGlmdDtIKGEpPWhjYXQoYSxmaWxsKCdcbicsMywxKSknO2E9Wyd8JyBmaWxsKCcgJywxLDcpXTtiPXJlcG1hdChDKFtmaWxsKCdfJywxLDgpO2E7YV0sWzAsb10pLDEsdyk7Yz1IKEMoYixbMCw0XSkpO2I9SChiKTtmb3IgaSBpbiAxOmg7aSUyPDE_cHJpbnQoYy4uLik6cHJpbnQoYi4uLik7ZW5k&input=)

Comment: ah. yes I did! :p

Comment: that actually makes it slightly easier! :D

Comment: You can save a few characters by using repmat instead of ones (`repmat([32],6,8)`), and then renaming repmat to shave another character (`g=repmat;b=g([32],6,8)` and later `b=g(b,h,w)[1:h,o+1:o+w+1]`). Then replace `reinterpret` with `map`. By my count, you'll save 9 bytes between these changes.

Comment: Actually it saves a lot more, since the Int32 requirement also disappears with map, and this also allows me to use repmat twice (it throws an error with Int32)! I can't believe I didn't `map` from the beginning (I guess I was stuck thinking of Char as a Type rather than also as a 'constructor'). Thanks, nice catch! :D

Comment: ... *or* ... you could just print a character array directly ... **d'oh!**

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <del>72</del> 66 bytes

```
->f,w,h{h.times{|i|puts i%3<1??_*w:((?|+' '*7)*w)[8-f+i%6/4*4,w]}}
```

Thanks @Value Ink for 6 bytes!

Simple string multiplication and slicing.

Works in Ruby 2.3.0 (Ideone's version 2.1 threw syntax error).

Comment: Use `i%6/4*4` instead of `(i%6>3?4:0)` and use `?_` instead of `'_'`, `?|` instead of `'|'`.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about `?` single char trick, and the "math" part is really impressive!

Comment: I think `((' '*7+?|)*w)[f^7^i%6&4,w]` saves you two bytes.

Comment: Thank you @Neil. I'll edit the code... as soon as I understand how your suggestion works :)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, <s>172</s> <s>168</s> <s>165</s> <s>157</s> <s>147</s> <s>142</s> 137 bytes

```
(O,W,H)=>{t='_'.repeat(W),x='|       '.repeat(W),f=t+`
`;for(i=0;++i<H;)f+=(!(i%3)?t:(i%6)>3?x.substr(O,W):x.substr(8-O,W))+`
`;return f}
```

```js
N = (O,W,H)=>{t='_'.repeat(W),x='|       '.repeat(W),f=t+`
`;for(i=0;++i<H;)f+=(!(i%3)?t:(i%6)>3?x.substr(O,W):x.substr(8-O,W))+`
`;return f}

let test_data = [[6,44,11],
                 [2,20,10],
                 [1,1,1],
                 [1,2,3],
                 [3,80,21]];

for (test of test_data)
    console.log(N(...test));
```

Comment: Why not use `s.repeat(w)` instead of `Array(w).fill(s).join\`\``?

Comment: @Neil: Good idea, but I thought of something better.

Comment: and then realized your solution is better than I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, 29 bytes

`↑⎕⍴⎕⍴¨a,4⌽¨a←'_',2⍴⊂⌽⎕⌽¯8↑'|'`

tests:
[`6 44 11`](http://tryapl.org/?a=F%20W%20H%u21906%2044%2011%20%u22C4%20%u2191H%u2374W%u2374%A8a%2C4%u233D%A8a%u2190%27_%27%2C2%u2374%u2282%u233DF%u233D%AF8%u2191%27%7C%27&run),
[`2 20 10`](http://tryapl.org/?a=F%20W%20H%u21902%2020%2010%20%u22C4%20%u2191H%u2374W%u2374%A8a%2C4%u233D%A8a%u2190%27_%27%2C2%u2374%u2282%u233DF%u233D%AF8%u2191%27%7C%27&run),
[`1 1 1`](http://tryapl.org/?a=F%20W%20H%u21901%201%201%20%u22C4%20%u2191H%u2374W%u2374%A8a%2C4%u233D%A8a%u2190%27_%27%2C2%u2374%u2282%u233DF%u233D%AF8%u2191%27%7C%27&run),
[`1 2 3`](http://tryapl.org/?a=F%20W%20H%u21901%202%203%20%u22C4%20%u2191H%u2374W%u2374%A8a%2C4%u233D%A8a%u2190%27_%27%2C2%u2374%u2282%u233DF%u233D%AF8%u2191%27%7C%27&run),
[`3 80 21`](http://tryapl.org/?a=F%20W%20H%u21903%2080%2021%20%u22C4%20%u2191H%u2374W%u2374%A8a%2C4%u233D%A8a%u2190%27_%27%2C2%u2374%u2282%u233DF%u233D%AF8%u2191%27%7C%27&run)

`⎕` is evaluated input; as the expression executes from right to left, it prompts for `F`, `W`, and `H` in that order

`¯8↑'|'` is `'       |'`

`⎕⌽` is rotate, it chops F chars from the front and puts them at the end of the string

the other `⌽` means reverse

`'_',2⍴⊂` creates a 3-tuple of '_' followed by two separate copies of the string so far

`a,4⌽¨a←` append the 4-rotation of everything so far, we end up with a 6-tuple

`⎕⍴¨` reshape each element to the width

`⎕⍴` reshape to the height

`↑` mix vector of vectors into a matrix

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>25</s> <s>24</s> 23 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'_'|7úD)³∍ε73N3÷è¹-._²∍
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Grimmy*.

Inputs in the order \$\text{offset}, \text{width}, \text{height}\$.
Output as a list of string-lines.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPV69xvzwLhfNQ5sfdfSe22pu7Gd8ePvhFYd26urFH9oEFPtfe2j3fzMuExMuQ0MA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpSbKWgZF@pw6XkX1oC5AJ5OpUJh1bGhIX@V49XrzE/vMtF89C6Rx2957aaG/sZH95@eEWErl58JFDkf@2h3TqaMYe22f@PjjbTMTHRMTSM1Yk20jEy0DE0ALIMdYAQTBvpGANpYx0LAx0jkIiBjqWOSWwsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
'_           '# Push "_"
'|           '# Push "|"
  7ú          # Pad 7 leading spaces: "       |"
    D         # Duplicate it
     )        # Wrap all three values on the stack into a list
³∍            # Extend this list to the (third) input-height amount of lines
              #  i.e. height=7 → ["_","       |","       |","_","       |","       |","_"]
ε             # Map over each line:
   N          #  Push the (0-based) map-index
    3÷        #  Integer-divide it by 3
 73   è       #  Index it into 73 (0-based and with wraparound)
              #   i.e. indices=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...] → [7,7,7,3,3,3,7,7,...]
       ¹+     #  Subtract the (first) input-offset
              #   i.e. offset=6 → [-3,-3,-3,1,1,1,-3,-3,...]
         ._   #  Rotate the string that many times towards the left
              #   i.e. ["_","       |","       |","_","       |","       |","_"] and 
              #     [-3,-3,-3,1,1,1,-3] → ["_","      | ","      | ","_","  |     ","  |     ","_"]
           ²∍ #  After this inner loop: push the (second) input-width
              #  Extend/shorten the line to a size equal to the (second) input-width
              #   i.e. width=5 and line="   |    " → "   | "
              #   i.e. width=20 and line="   |    " → "   |       |       |"
              #   i.e. width=5 and line="_" → "_____"
              #   i.e. width=20 and line="_" → "____________________"
              # (after which the list of string-lines is output implicitly as result)
```

`73N3÷è` could alternatively be `₃€ÐÍNè` for the same byte-count:

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9vc2FiaWX//ydfJ3w3w7pEKcKz4oiNzrXigoPigqzDkMONTsOowrktLl/CsuKIjf99wrv/Ngo0NAoxMQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpSbKWgZF@pw6XkX1oC5AJ5OpUJh1bGhIX@V49XrzE/vMtF89C6Rx2957Y@amp@1LTm8ITDvX6HV0To6sVHAoX/1x7araMZc2ib/f/oaDMdExMdQ8NYnWgjHSMDHUMDIMtQBwjBtJGOMZA21rEw0DECiRjoWOqYxMYCAA).

```python
 ₃            #  Push builtin 95
  €Ð          #  Triplicate each digit: [9,9,9,5,5,5]
    Í         #  Decrease each by 2: [7,7,7,3,3,3]
     Nè       #  Index the (0-based) map-index into this (0-based and with wraparound)
```

Comment: [I had to go to great lengths to golf just one byte off this.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f9ejeI@2HFx5p8zu8QvvQRvUa88O71OMfNcwCi@jFH9r0qKNX5/9/Q0MuExMuMwA) (input order is the reverse of what you use)

Comment: @Grimmy Oh, very nice. I was trying to figure out how to use implicit input, but couldn't really figure it out. Smart way to using the second input implicitly in the first iteration, since it's irrelevant for the rotation of the `"_"` anyway. And also smart of using `._` with the bitwise-NOT `±`, since that one can be either `integer,string` or `string,integer` as arguments, whereas the `ƒÁ}` I used has to be `string,integer`! You weren't kidding when you said you went to great lengths for that -1! ;D

Comment: @Grimmy I just read that the output may be a list of string-lines, so I guess we both had a 24-byter. ;)

Comment: In that case, [here's 23](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPV69xvzwLhfNQ5sfdfSe22pu7Gd8ePvhFYd26urFH9oEFPtfe2j3fzMuExMuQ0MA) ([alt](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9vc2FiaWX//ydfJ3w3w7pEKcKz4oiNzrXigoPigqzDkMONTsOowrktLl/CsuKIjf99wrv/Ngo0NAoxMQ))

Comment: @Grimmy Nice one! I especially like that alternative with the `₃€ÐÍ`. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), <s>44</s> <s>43</s> 40 bytes

This is an Actually port of the algorithm in [Neil's JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90076/47581). Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8///R1OmPps4tetSzwNpMQ9VE7dHUOeZxcY@mzlavMVdSUNLS1ioBchw8QCLxWsYaqpGej3oW@mb@/29oyGViwmUGAA)

```
╗╝r⌠;6(%4&╜7^^╛'|7" "*+*t╛@H╛'_*3(%YI⌡Mi
```

**Ungolfing:**

```
          Takes implicit input in the order h, w, f.
╗╝        Save f to register 0. Save w to register 1.
r⌠...⌡M   Map over range [0..h-1]. Call this variable i.
  ;         Duplicate i
  6(%       i%6...
  4&        ...&4
  ╜7^^      ...^i^7. Call it c.
  ╛         Push w.
  '|7" "*+  The string "       |"
  *t╛@H     (("       |" * w)[c:])[:w]
  ╛'_*      Push "_" * w
  3(%       Push 3, move duplicate i to TOS, mod.
  YI        If not i%3, take "_"*w, else (("       |" * w)[c:])[:w]
            Function ends here.
i         Flatten the resulting list and print the bricks implicitly.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>101</s> 88 bytes

```powershell
param($n,$w,$h)0..--$h|%{(('|       '*$w|% S*g(8-$n+4*($_%6-gt3))$w),('_'*$w))[!($_%3)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3RCoJAEEXf9ys2GdsZG2NXJSLoK@otRCQsH8xEhX1Iv31zrWG4nDt34HZvW/VDXTWNg8f547qyL18ILYNlqEnv93EM9RR@ENUkf6MisFMoL9ETjzG0uyxCKMJD/BxTIrDEqAr/Q3Tb@CSlfHazEIgHzjI2hlhgwolmoz0aln7/mLBMPaYsj3qxhmipF744uFbDKO/lUJ0kFMF6k1t4LOamc69m1SRfI6XE7L4)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 30 bytes

```
(n₃[¹\_*,|7\|꘍¹*⁰ǔǔn3ḭ∷[4ǔ]¹Ẏ,
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%28n%E2%82%83%5B%C2%B9%5C_*%2C%7C7%5C%7C%EA%98%8D%C2%B9*%E2%81%B0%C7%94%C7%94n3%E1%B8%AD%E2%88%B7%5B4%C7%94%5D%C2%B9%E1%BA%8E%2C&inputs=10%0A44%0A1&header=&footer=)

A big mess.

```
(                              # (height) times (to make each row)
 n₃[                           # If the iteration is divisible by 3 (flat row) then...
    ¹\_*,                      # (width) underscores
         |                     # Else (part of a brick)...
          7\|꘍                 # Prepend seven spaces to an underscore
              ¹*               # Repeat (width) times
                ⁰ǔǔ            # Cycle by (offset), then cycle once more
                   n3ḭ∷[  ]    # If it's an offset row
                        4ǔ     # Cycle once more
                           ¹Ẏ, # Trim to the correct length and print.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Octave <s>80</s> 76 bytes

```
% in file codegolf.m
c(6,8)=0;c([1,4],:)=63;c([2,3,23,24])=92;char(repmat(c+32,h,w)(1:h,o+1:o+w))
```

to run from terminal: `octave --eval "o=2;h=18;w=44; codegolf"`

(alternatively, if you think the terminal call is cheating :p then an anonymous function implementation takes 86 bytes :)

```
c(6,8)=0;c([1,4],:)=63;c([2,3,23,24])=92;f=@(o,h,w)char(repmat(c+32,h,w)(1:h,o+1:o+w))
```

Call `f(2,18,44)` at the octave interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + Sed, <s>411</s> <s>395</s> <s>381</s> 370 bytes:

```Bash
F=`printf '_%.s' $(eval echo {1..$2})`;V="       |";(($[($2-$1)/8]>0))&&L=`printf "$V%.s" $(eval echo {1..$[($2-$1)/8]})`||L=;Z=`printf "%$1.s|%s\n" e "$L"`;I=$[($2-(${#Z}-4))/8];(($I>0))&&W=`printf "$V%.s" $(eval echo {1..$I})`||W=;J=${Z:4}$W;for i in `eval echo {1..$[$3/3+1]}`;{ (($[$i%2]<1))&&O+="$F\n$J\n$J\n"||O+="$F\n$Z\n$Z\n";};echo "`echo -e "$O"|sed -n 1,$3p`"
```

Well, here is my very first answer in Bash, or any shell scripting language for that matter. This is also by far the longest answer here. Takes in a sequence of space-separated command line arguments in the format `Offset Width Height`. This can probably be a lot shorter than it currently is, so any tips and/or tricks for golfing this down more are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### Delphi/Object Pascal, <strike>305</strike>, <strike>302</strike>, 292 bytes

Full console program that reads 3 parameters.

```
uses SySutils,Math;var i,q,o,w,h:byte;begin o:=StrToInt(paramstr(1));w:=StrToInt(paramstr(2));h:=StrToInt(paramstr(3));for q:=0to h-1do begin for i:=1to w do if q mod 3=0then Write('_')else if IfThen(Odd(q div 3),((i+o)mod 8),((i-o)mod 8))=1then Write('|')else Write(' ');Writeln('');end end.
```

#### ungolfed

```
uses
  SySutils,
  Math;
var
  i,q,o,w,h:byte;
begin
  o:=StrToInt(paramstr(1));
  w:=StrToInt(paramstr(2));
  h:=StrToInt(paramstr(3));

  for q := 0 to h-1 do
  begin
    for i := 1 to w do
      if q mod 3 = 0  then
        Write('_')
      else
        if IfThen(Odd(q div 3),((i+o)mod 8),((i-o)mod 8)) = 1 then
          Write('|')
        else Write(' ');
    Writeln('');
  end
end.
```

Sadly, Delphi does not have a ternary operator and it is quite a verbose language.

#### test case

```
D:\Test\CodeGolfWall\Win32\Debug>Project1.exe 2 20 10
____________________
  |       |       |
  |       |       |
____________________
      |       |
      |       |
____________________
  |       |       |
  |       |       |
____________________

D:\Test\CodeGolfWall\Win32\Debug>Project1.exe 6 44 11
____________________________________________
      |       |       |       |       |
      |       |       |       |       |
____________________________________________
  |       |       |       |       |       |
  |       |       |       |       |       |
____________________________________________
      |       |       |       |       |
      |       |       |       |       |
____________________________________________
  |       |       |       |       |       |
```

Edit: Could shave of 3 bytes by using byte as type for all variables.

Edit 2: And console applications do not *need* the program declaration, -10

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>81 78</s>  77 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @mypronounismonicareinstate*

Takes input as `(F, W)(H)`.

```javascript
(F,W,x=y=0)=>g=H=>y<H?`
|_ `[x++<W?y%3?(x+~F^y/3<<2)&7?3:1:2:x=+!++y]+g(H):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bczBCsIgAIDhe09hh5qi1dRRITpvY2@wQ1QbaxvFmNEiFKJXN6@xzh//f6te1Vg/rvfnajCXxrfKw4wUxCqnYqTSTuUqdTLX5ex9BuXBYiwL7RZcQ4s/2cltuJQMLXeaCyqYsArPMXZH3MEciSjytRlG0zfr3nSwhVsCkgRBShGa/QojgMVB4olQAgBFENC/woLwiXAC9uHGQuO/)

Comment: Why not `(F,W)=>g=....` and take input as `(F, W)(H)`?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Doing just that would be 1 byte longer. But it does allow to initialize `x` and `y` within the arguments of the 1st arrow function and getting rid of the 2nd argument in the recursive call, saving 3 bytes. I guess that's what you had in mind? Thanks!

Comment: No, that is not what I had in mind (for some reason I thought that was a byte shorter) :)