# Build me a brick wall!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

### Challenge

I need help building a brick wall! Throw together some code for me
 using no input and produce the following output wall shown below:

```
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Now, this wall is exactly `10` characters high and `70` characters
 wide.

As stated above, no inputs, only code. Least amount of bytes, we have
 to efficiently build this brick wall. Obviously, this program has to
 function to get the wall built..? or it obviously won't build itself!
 Good luck!

---

### Winner

The winner goes to **Marinus** using the `APL` language, requiring a whole `12` bytes!
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99028/61857

---

Thank you everyone for participating!

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90022/all-in-all-its-just-uh-another-trick-in-code-golf), [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49536/build-a-steady-brick-wall),

Comment: [Also Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67452/help-trump-build-the-wall) (odd that this should come up today, haha)

Comment: This would be around 10 bytes in [Crayon](https://github.com/ETHproductions/crayon), too bad there's no interpreter yet...

Comment: could you provide a screenshot possibly @ETHproductions? thanks!

Comment: [Who's gonna build your wall?](https://www.antiwarsongs.org/canzone.php?id=7587)

Comment: @dylan I'm sorry, a screenshot of what? I don't have an interpreter yet, and the spec isn't even finalized, so I can't write the exact code...

Comment: i thought you meant online interpreter, but yeah I understand. sorry for the miscommunication @ETHproductions

Comment: That's OK. I'll let you know when I have a working interpreter. I'm working on it right now, actually :)

Comment: [Related](http://trumpdonald.org/)!

Comment: For bonus points, make Mexico pay for it.

Comment: Donald Trump just found cheap workmanship here!

Comment: Haha, just stumbled across this challenge and I remembered being salty when this challenge came out as I had just put a [very similar one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10446/60919) in the sandbox.

Comment: May we output a list of lines?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## APL, 12 bytes

```
10 70⍴'_|__'
```

Output:

```
      10 70⍴'_|__'
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Comment: I just noticed this answer as I put my J answer. they're basically the same haha

Comment: This outputs something else in addition to the ascii wall. Is this allowed?

Comment: when using tryapl.org, I got the wall output. what have you received @TheBitByte?

Comment: @Dylan He's probably confused, since the answerer included the program in the output without knowing the REPL nature of APL.

Answer (score 193):

### [Trumpscript](https://github.com/samshadwell/TrumpScript), <s>303</s> <s>285</s> <s>244</s> <s>231</s> 226 bytes

```
make i 1000005-1000000
as long as,i;:
make i,i - fact;
say "_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|"
say "___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__"!
America is great
```

I would like to say this is one of the most verbose languages where almost everything fails to compile into a working program.

Apparently whether `-` works instead of `minus` is completely up to the interpreter and sometimes works. This time it did so I'm putting it in as golfed.

Abuses the fact Trumpscript is written in Python and therefore `fact` when used as an integer is one.

Golfing tips welcome.

Comment: I take it Trumpscript doesn't allow numbers less than 1,000,000? ;-)

Comment: you are correct.

Comment: Can you use `i is 1000005-1000000` and `i is i-fact`? (Just taken a look at the readme of Trumpscript.)

Comment: @AlexRacer I'll update once I get to a computer with a Trumpscript interpreter so I can test that

Comment: Doesn't python have a way to multiply a string?
e.g.: `say "_|_" x 35`

Comment: I'm surprised it allows you to use `1000000`. [Documentation](https://github.com/samshadwell/TrumpScript#features) states `All numbers must be strictly greater than 1 million. The small stuff is inconsequential to us.`.

Comment: `Fact` and `lies` (and other truth/false constants) have a random, time based chance to flip flop (be reversed) during tokenization (see tokenizer.py, search flip_flop) may be why it seemed to not work with `minus`, when really it had to do with `fact` at that point in time

Comment: Actually, the code`s 0 bytes. The 226 bytes come from the file. Fact.

Comment: [232](https://tio.run/##KykqzS0oTi7KLCj5/z83MTtVIVPB0AAETHUhtEFisUJOfl66QmKxTqa1FUSNTqaCNlQaqszQmqs4sVJBKb4mPp5yrAQxK54apikpOuamFmUmJypkFiukF6UmAn0KAA), doesn't use `fact` so no possible failing depending on time

Answer (score 21):

## J, 12 bytes

```
10 70$'_|__'
```

Shapes the string on the right into a 10 by 70 shape. Simple!

Answer (score 18):

## BBC BASIC, 28 bytes

Tokenised filesize 23 bytes.

```
WIDTH70P.STRING$(175,"_|__")
```

`WIDTH70` would normally be followed by a newline. It sets the field width to 70. Then we just print 175 copies of the string, which wrap around.

Comment: Best (ab)use of WIDTH that I have seen :)

Comment: This should have "23 bytes" in the header then.

Comment: @Adám Only if the tokenized version is posted as the answer.

Answer (score 17):

## Brainfuck, 171 bytes

```
+++++[>+++++++++++++++++++<-]+++++++[>>++++++++++++++++++<<-]>>--<<++[>>>+++++<<<-]+++++[>.>.>>+++++++++++++++++[<<<...>.>>-]<.>+++++++++++++++++[<<<...>.>>-]<<<..>>.<<<-]
```

Brainfuck is fun, here is my submission.

Here is the output:

```
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Here is a link to try it

https://repl.it/EW2Z/0

Answer (score 16):

## WinDbg, 45 bytes

```
f2000000 L2bc 5f 7c 5f 5f;da/c46 2000000 L2bc
```

How it works:

```
f 2000000 L2bc 5f 7c 5f 5f; *Repeat the pattern _|__ (5F 7C 5F 5F) to fill 2BC (700) bytes 
                            *starting at 2000000
da /c46 2000000 L2bc        *Show 2BC (700) ASCII chars starting from 2000000 in lines 
                            *of length 0x46 (70)
```

Output:

```
0:000> f2000000 L2bc 5f 7c 5f 5f;da/c46 2000000 L2bc
Filled 0x2bc bytes
02000000  "_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|"
02000046  "___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__"
0200008c  "_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|"
020000d2  "___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__"
02000118  "_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|"
0200015e  "___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__"
020001a4  "_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|"
020001ea  "___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__"
02000230  "_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|"
02000276  "___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__"
```

Answer (score 10):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

Code:

```
jcT*175"_|__
```

Explanation:

```
       "_|__    # For the string "_|__"
   *175         # Repeat it 175 times
 cT             # Chop into 10 equal pieces
j               # Join them by newlines
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jcT%2a175%22_%7C__&debug=0).

Answer (score 10):

### Python 2, 37 bytes

```python
s="_|__"*17;print(s+"_|\n__%s\n"%s)*5
```

Decomposes two rows as 17 copies of `_|__`, plus another copy interrupted by a newline, plus 17 more copies, plus another newline.

Longer alternatives:

```python
print"%s_|\n__%s\n"%(2*("_|__"*17,))*5

s="_|__"*17;print"%s_|\n__%%s\n"%s%s*5

for i in[0,2]*5:print("_|__"*18)[i:i+70]

print("_|__"*17+"_|\n"+"___|"*17+"__\n")*5

for s in["_|__","___|"]*5:print(s*18)[:70]

s="_|__"*99;exec"print s[:70];s=s[2:];"*10

print("%s"*70+"\n")*10%(175*tuple("_|__"))
```

Comment: Your last alternative is shorter as `print(("%s"*70+"\n")*10%(175*(*"_|__",)))` in Python 3.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

Code:

```
"_|__"175×Tä»
```

Explanation:

```
"_|__"         # For the string "_|__"
      175×     # Repeat that 175 times
          Tä   # Split into 10 even pieces
            »  # And join them by newlines
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Il98X18iMTc1w5dUw6TCuw&input=)

Comment: -2 by using `…_|_Ć` and the compressed `Ƶм` for 175 (I realize the second wasn't available when you posted the answer; not sure about the first).

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, <s>44</s> <s>42</s> 41 characters

```php
<?=chunk_split(str_pad(_,700,"|___"),70);
```

(Just because had no chance to use `chunk_split()` ever before.)

Thanks to:

- [user59178](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59178/user59178) for suggesting to use `str_pad()` (-1 character)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ php <<< '<?=chunk_split(str_pad(_,700,"|___"),70);'
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Comment: bytes, not character count.

Comment: Same. I use no multibyte characters.

Comment: [Crossed out 44 is still regular 44 ;(](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7427/55372)

Comment: @pajonk, Fixed with [PPCG - Crossed Out 44](https://bitbucket.org/manatwork/ppcg-style/src/75f87e68d4b19c08014e5f320d2e6e0101529bca/PPCG%20-%20Crossed%20Out%2044.css?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) user style on my machine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/czn5h.png

Comment: You can save a byte by using `str_pad` instead of `str_repeat`, largely because `_` is treated as a constant with value `_`.

Answer (score 7):

### Vim, <s>30</s> <s>24</s> 19 keystrokes

```
18a___|<esc>YP2x}h.yk4P
```

Thanks to DrMcMoylex and nmjcman101 for saving valuable keystrokes!

Comment: Nice answer, welcome to the site! Some tips: 1) `a` takes a count, so you could do `18a___|<esc>` instead of making the macro. 2) `<cr>` in normal mode is equivalent to `j0`, so you could take one byte off your second macro.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tips!

Comment: I golfed your solution a bit for fun.  Formatting the wall before copy/pasting saves all the bytes of not making a macro: `18a___|<esc>YP2x}h.yk5P` is 19 bytes.

Comment: Nice, I'll update the answer! I'll just replace the second to last key with 4, otherwise the wall is getting too high :)

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, <s>47</s> <s>34</s> 29 bytes

```
$_="_|__"x175;say for/.{70}/g
```

Comment: You can golf it down to 29 : `say for("_|__"x175)=~/.{70}/g`

Comment: For some reason, that used to produce no output every time I tried it, but I found another solution in as many bytes.  Thank you though!

Comment: Well, the code I suggested does produce a valid output... Maybe you forgot the parenthesis around `"_|__"x175` or something like that?

Comment: I think that's what it is.  I figured parentheses had to go somewhere, I just couldn't figure out where, lol

Comment: Huhu, hard to remember the precedence of every operator (`=~` has a higher precedence than `x`)!

Comment: I always seem to have tabs with  `perlre`, `perlop`, and `perlrun` open at all times for that very reason :P

Answer (score 5):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>24</s>, 16 bytes

```
175i_|__ò70|lé
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=MTc1aV98X18bw7I3MHxsw6kK&input=)
This contains `<esc>` characters (`0x1B`) so here is a hexdump:

```
0000000: 3137 3569 5f7c 5f5f 1bf2 3730 7c6c e90a  175i_|__..70|l..
```

8 bytes indirectly saved thanks to Jordan!

Comment: 19 bytes: http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=MTc1aV98X18bw5MuXHs3MH0vwrDDsg&input= I couldn't figure out how to use the `.\{-}` shortcut [mentioned in the V docs](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/wiki/Regexes#shortcuts), though.

Comment: @Jordan Wow, very nice! The `\{-}` shortcut wouldn't work anyway, since you can't change the number inside. However, you could set the high bit on the `\{` to get [this](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=MTc1aV98X18bw5Muw7s3MH0vwrDDsg&input=) instead. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Posted here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99070/11261

Comment: Damn I still need to grok this language: [25 bytes](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=YV9fX3wbMDE4w6RFMTDDhDXDsTJ4aiR4eDBqw7E&input=)

Answer (score 5):

### Perl, 31 bytes

```pl
say+($@="_|__"x17,"_|
__$@
")x5
```

You'll need `-E` flag to run it :

```
perl -E 'say+($@="_|__"x17,"_|
__$@
")x5'
```

Comment: Thought of a slightly different approach for 29 bytes: `say for("_|__"x175)=~/.{70}/g` :). I do like the trick you employed there though!

Comment: @DomHastings huhu, I wrote the exact same code in the comments of Gabriel Benamy's answer!

Comment: D'oh! Didn't see that one! Also then saw it's been used _a lot_ in other answers.. Oh well!

Comment: @DomHastings Yea, I didn't thought of it at first, and it was already in Gabriel's answer, so that's why I didn't update my answer after ;)

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>46</s> 44 Bytes

Just using string multiplication to build the string, and slicing to get the right bits :)

```
k='_|__'*18
print'\n'.join([k[:70],k[2:]]*5)
```

<sup>*thanks to Antony Hatchkins for saving two bytes :)*</sup>

Comment: Could be 2 bytes less: `print'\n'.join([k[:70],k[2:]]*5)`

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 18 bytes

-1 byte thanks to DJMcMayhem.

```
175i_|__<Esc>Ó.û70}/°ò
```

Here it is with unprintable characters in xxd format:

```
0000000: 3137 3569 5f7c 5f5f 1bd3 2efb 3730 7d2f  175i_|__....70}/
0000010: b0f2                                     ..
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=MTc1aV98X18bw5Muw7s3MH0vwrDDsg&input=)

Comment: Nice, I am no longer the only person who has used V! Now I'm going to have to see if I can take the lead back, haha

Answer (score 5):

## MATL, 15 bytes

```
'_|__'700:)70e!
```

Of course, you can [Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=J198X18nNzAwOik3MGUh&input=)
Explanation:

```
'_|__' % Put a brick on the stack
700    % 700 times
:)     % Makes a happy mason...
70e!   % Secret freemason code
```

OK, actually, it works as follows:

```
'_|__' % Put the first bit of the string on the stack
700:   % Put 1, 2, ..., 700 on the stack as array
)      % Index into the string, modularly. Result: '_|___|__ ... __'
70e    % Reshape into 70 rows (and consequently, 10 columns)
!      % Transpose to get the desired output.
```

Comment: Well done! And your smiley is better than mine

Comment: @LuisMendo Really, using smileys could be considered a design pattern in MATL. xD Perhaps you could have `:)` on `C`... but that would be your last 1-byte code point gone (or is there another reason `C` is not used?)

Comment: You want to get rid of the smiley?? :-P

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“_|__”ṁ700s70Y
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcX3xfX-KAneG5gTcwMHM3MFk&input=)**

#### How?

```
“_|__”ṁ700s70Y - Main link: no arguments
“_|__”         - literal ['_','|','_','_']
      ṁ700     - mould like something 700 long
          s70  - split into chunks of length 70
             Y - join with line feeds
```

Comment: By definition, Jelly cannot be longer than J.

Comment: I did something similar without the peculiar `ṁ`: `“_|__”ẋ175œs⁵Y` (14 bytes)

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>34</s> 30 bytes

```
'_|__'*175-split"(.{70})"-ne''
```

Stupid regex matching algorithm requiring the `-ne''` ... wastes five bytes!

```
'_|__'*175-split"(.{70})"-ne''
'_|__'*175                     # Repeat this string 175 times
          -split"       "      # Split on this regex pattern:
                  .{70}        # Match any character 70 times
                 (     )       # Encapsulated in parens so we keep the regex results
                         -ne'' # But don't select the empty strings
                               # Output with newlines via Write-Output is implicit
```

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to Conor!*

Comment: Would `.{70}` be any shorter for teh regex?

Comment: `split` works like that in other languages - you always get the unmatched portions whether you want them or not. Some languages have a `match` operator that can be used to return an array of only matching results, but I don't see a PowerShell equivalent for that.

Comment: @Neil Performing `'abc'-split'(.)'` will return `('','a','','b','','c','')`. There's nothing unmatched, but due to how the algorithm processes through the input string, you get empty strings back. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.nextmatch(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, and I'm saying you shouldn't be surprised by that result, because that's what split's supposed to do.

Comment: @Neil Surprised? No, not really. Doesn't mean I have to be happy about it, though. :D

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>131</s> <s>115</s> <s>113</s> <s>103</s> <s>97</s> 95 Bytes

```
i,j;main(){for(;i<10;puts(i++&1?"|__":"|"))for(j=0;j<18-(i&1);printf(&"|___"[j++?0:i&1?1:3]));}
```

Time to start golfing this...

```
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/T1tDAOjcxM09Ds7o4I7@oRCEx2sIg1jotv0ijPDc1tzi1RCNRR70mPj5eXcfIQNM6U1fXuqC0pFhDSUlTs7wosyRVw1AnUTtT1UjHHChd@/8/AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 16 bytes

```
'___|'10:E!70:+)
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=J19fX3wnMTA6RSE3MDorKQ&input=)

```
'___|'   % Push this string
10:E!    % Push [2; 4; 6; ...; 20] (10×1 column vector)
70:      % Push [1, 2, 3, ..., 70] (1×70 row vector)
+        % Add. Gives a 10×70 matrix of all pairwise additions
)        % Index (modular, 1-based) into the string
```

Comment: Beat you with an entire byte: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99073/32352

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 15 bytes

```
"_|__"175*70/N*
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=Il98X18iMTc1KjcwL04q&input=)

Port of [Adnan's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99032/36398).

```
"_|__"             e# Push this string
      175*         e# Repeat 175 times
          70/      e# Split in pieces of size 70
             N*    e# Join by newlines
```

Answer (score 3):

**Javascript REPL, 45 bytes**

```
"_|__".repeat(175).match(/.{70}/g).join("\n")
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This should be marked as "JavaScript REPL" or similar, as this doesn't print anything at all outside of an interactive console environment.

Comment: Isn't this 45 bytes?

Comment: @daHugLenny you are right, I counted \n as a single byte

Comment: where is the console.log ?

Comment: As long as you are using ES6 (I think it is) you can use template strings, so `join("\n")` becomes join<backtick><literal newline><backtick>

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 48 bytes

```
f=(n=350)=>n?(n%35?'_':`
_`)+"|_"[n%2]+f(n-1):""
```

Because recursion.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, <strike>44, 41</strike>, 40 bytes

```
printf _\|__%.0s {1..175}|egrep -o .{70}
```

The printf makes a single line 700 characters long, the egrep matches it 70 characters at a time.

Answer (score 3):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 43 bytes

```
/a/___|//b/aaccccc//c/aaa//d/_|b
b__
/ddddd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcaxDQAgDAPBnmV@JMsBJAq6tOwe4KrL7VwzqzCSDgR2/6C/GgY60UJqjK/qAg)

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), 63 bytes

```
'_\:3+4%0`!> #0 #\ #|' $ #\_\,1+:7a*%0`!> #0 #, #a_:7aa**\`!#@_
```

[TryItOnline!](http://befunge-98.tryitonline.net/#code=J19cOjMrNCUwYCE-ICMwICNcICN8JyAkICNcX1wsMSs6N2EqJTBgIT4gIzAgIywgI2FfOjdhYSoqXGAhI0Bf&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 30 bytes

Thanks to manatwork for this solution

```
puts ("_|__"*175).scan /.{70}/
```

## Ruby, 39 bytes

```
10.times{|i|puts ("_|__"*18)[i%2*2,70]}
```

Comment: The generate-all-then-split approach is shorter here too: `puts ("_|__"*175).scan /.{70}/`.

Comment: @manatwork thanks a lot! I rarely think of using `scan` as I´m not that comfortable with regexes. You know you could have posted that as your own answer...

Answer (score 2):

## ///, 51 bytes

If a trailing newline is allowed:

```
/e/aaaa//a/_|__//b/eeeea_|//c/__eeeea//d/b
c
/ddddd
```

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L2UvYWFhYS8vYS9ffF9fLy9iL2VlZWVhX3wvL2MvX19lZWVlYS8vZC9iCmMKL2RkZGRk&input=)

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 12 bytes

```
w�"_|__"*TfX
```

where `�` is the literal byte 163.

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=175%22_%7C__%22%2aTfX) (`w�` replaced with literal)

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, <s>23</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
175$*_

_|_
!`.{70}
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=CjE3NSQqXwoKX3xfCiFgLns3MH0&input=)

Comment: Use `!\`.{70}` to split the string at the end.

Comment: You can save another byte like this: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=CjE3NSQqXwoKX3xfCiFgLns3MH0&input=

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>56</s> 47 bytes

```
unlines$[1..5]>>take 70.cycle<$>["_|__","___|"]
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 78 bytes

```
    strwrap(gsub('(.{70})','\\1 ',paste(rep('___|',175),collapse='')),70)
```

How?

```
    x=paste(rep('___|',175),collapse='')   #Creates string on 1 line
    y=gsub('(.{70})','\\1 ',x)             #Adds spaces every 70 characters
    z=strwrap(y,70)                        #Creates a new line every space
    z                                      #Print the finished product
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 61 bytes

TCC Version

```
main(i){for(;i+699;)printf("\n%c"+(--i%70||!i),"___|"[i&3]);}
```

GCC Version

```
main(i){for(;i+699;)printf("\n%c"+(i%70||!i),"___|"[--i&3]);}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge-93, 42 bytes

```
:4%1g,1+:"F"%!#v_0#@_
_|__~>:+#5,#:4#<1g*`^
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=OjQlMWcsMSs6IkYiJSEjdl8wI0BfCl98X19-PjorIzUsIzo0IzwxZypgXg&input=)

Comment: Nice answer. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

## bash 36 Byte

```
printf '_|__%.0s' {1..175}|fold -w70
```

OUtput:

```
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Comment: You can omit the `w` in `fold -w70`

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 40 bytes

```
p="_|__"*17
print((p+"_|\n__"+p+"\n")*5)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 45 bytes

```javascript
_=>`_|__`.repeat(175).match(/.{70}/g).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBEoAQFADQfSdh0VeLxkpXwQgx8g2mTXV2vRf1rZupofQ542GHE0OKXclXSgXVFqs7WflG4dLdnITBw5ePeQoRQ1aTGgZzw2QhoSeOUDp@)

## Explanation :

```javascript
_ =>                    // lambda function (argument passed to save a byte)
    `_|__`              // simple enough
    .repeat(175)        // repeat the above mentioned shape 175 times
    .match(/.{70}/g)    // simple regexp to match a shape 70 (something :) ) long 
    .join`\n`           // and join them on a new line
```

---

Simple enough.

## Alternate version :

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 714 bytes

```javascript
_=>`_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i4hviY@nnLMRQ1D4uO5Rl0z6hoycML/5Py84vycVL2c/HSNNA1Nzf8A)

No explanation required. Simple hard coded.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
70:þ⁵“_|__”ṁY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/cwOrwvkeNWx81zImviY9/1DD34c7GyP//AQ)

The dyad given to `þ` doesn't matter so long as it outputs a scalar, so I chose `:` solely for aesthetic purposes.

```
   þ             Take the rangifying outer product
  :              by integer division
70               of 70
    ⁵            and 10,
     “_|__”ṁ     mold "_|__" like it,
            Y    and join on newlines.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
…_|_ĆƵм×Tä»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9vc2FiaWX//@KApl98X8SGxrXQvMOXVMOkwrv//w)

```
         ä   # split...
…            # three char string...
 _|_         # literal...
    Ć        # concatenated with its first character...
       ×     # repeated...
      м      # numeric literal...
     Ƶ       # converted from base 255 to decimal plus 101...
       ×     # times...
         ä   # into...
        T    # 10...
         ä   # equal pieces...
          »  # by newlines
             # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```
for b in range(10):print('_|__'*175)[b*70:][:70]
```

2 saved with thanks to @xnor but also thanks to @Shebang for the suggestion :)

Comment: `b*70+70 -> -~b*70` saves a byte :)

Comment: Or `[b*70:][:70]`.

Comment: Thanks @xnor. Didn't know you could do that. may well go back and trim a couple off some of my other recent answers :)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <strike>106</strike> <strike>102</strike> <strike>101</strike> <strike>118</strike> <strike>107</strike> <strike>106</strike> <strike>100</strike> 96 bytes

Thanks shebang for saving 2 bytes and pointing out a mistake, Yodle for saving 6 bytes and Link Ng for saving 4 bytes.

```
var a="";int i;for(;i++<175;)a+="_|__";for(i=0;i<10;)Console.Write(a.Substring(i++*10,70)+"\n");
```

You can test it directly on http://csharppad.com/.

Comment: Change the `a%2==0` to `a%2<1` to save a byte :)

Comment: Also, you can remove the `a++` in the `for` definition and change `a%2` to `a++%2`!

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by declaring i outside the loop, incrementing i within the condition i<175, and using i in the second loop instead of a new integer b.

Comment: @Yodle I could save 6 bytes by doing so (and not 4), thanks!

Comment: Ahh I guess they have a default value of 0 :P.   In VS it won't let you declare local variables without initializing them, so the =0 made it only 4 for me.

Comment: Remove the two pairs of curly braces for 4 bytes

Comment: Could you do this and save 2 bytes? int i;for(;i<10;)Console.Write(string.Join("_|__",new string[75]).Substring(i++*10,70)+ "\n");  http://csharppad.com/gist/92a5bcefaeaeb90a96a9cc367593b1c5

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 17 bytes

```
RZc*"_|__"Τ755@FS
```

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=UlpjKiJffF9fIs6kNzU1QEZT)

### Explanation

```
RZc*"_|__"Τ755@FS
   *"_|__"         repeat this string:
          Τ755      7*5*5 = 175 times
 Zc           @F   chop into groups of 70 (F's charcode)
R               S  join by newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SOML](https://github.com/dzaima/SOML), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOML/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
_|__”’ø*L{:jjp»»
```

explanation:

```
_|__”             push "_|__"
     ’ø           push 18
       *          repeat the "_|__" 18 times
        L{        repeat 10 times:
          :       duplicate the sting
           jj     pop the last 2 letters off
             p    output it
              »»  put the last 2 characters at the start
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
VT:*175"_|__"J*70N+70J
```

OK, I'm still learning. Any hints gratefully received :)

**Edit**

Saved a byte by moving the assignment of J to first use

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8 + Guava, <s>81</s> 106 bytes

25 bytes for import: `com.google.common.base.*;`

Lambda that takes no input and returns the required wall.

```
()->String.join("\n",Splitter.fixedLength(70).split(Strings.repeat("_|__",175)));
```

Same as many other solutions. Takes a repeating string of "_|__" 175 times, splits it into lengths of 70, then joins them on newline.

Comment: Don't you need imports for this?

Comment: @mbomb007 That's why I put '+ Guava' in the title. I assumed that was sufficient.

Comment: Imports must be included in the byte count. https://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/10081/34718; https://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8782/34718

Answer (score 1):

### GolfSharp, 38 bytes

```
c(r(175).s(n=>"_|__").j().S(70).j(N));
```

Comment: is it this [language](https://github.com/timopomer/GolfSharp/)?

Comment: @aloisdg it is fellow typo corrector! You warmed my heart

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 46 bytes

```
<?=wordwrap(str_repeat('_|__',175),70,"\n",1);
```

**Output:**

```
C:\PHP>php build-me-a-brick-wall.php
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Comment: I think `wordwrap()`'s 3rd parameter should be `"\n"` as this currently keeps the string unwrapped in PHP 5.6.

Comment: @manatwork In the "test online" link you can check the various versions of PHP, it seems working fine in PHP all versions.

Comment: Correct, “seems”. But the output is wrapped by the sandbox site, not by PHP. See with “Output: Raw”.

Comment: @manatwork I thought the textbox output is acceptable too. I tryed with  `<?=wordwrap(str_repeat('_|__',175),70,"\n",1); ` and still no wraps in Raw output while it works fine if you save it in a PHP file and run in a browser.

Comment: Well, relying on the sandbox sounds similar to what was discussed in [When is code that requires a REPL acceptable?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7842/when-is-code-that-requires-a-repl-acceptable). So if you add it to the post title, should be fine. (Honestly, I still not like the idea.) BTW, you can just wrap the line in that place instead of writing `\n`, to keep the code size at original 45.

Comment: @manatwork I added the PHP interpreted version called by console.

Comment: `chunk_split` will save four bytes over `wordwrap`, because you don´t need the 3rd and 4th parameter. Funny: `str_pad("",700,"_|__")` has the same length as `str_repeat("_|__",175)`.

Comment: @Titus I know, but I didn't want to copy the other answer :) Someone used that before me and the answers would have been too much similar or almost the same...

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 159 bytes

```
(let p((n 2)(x 0)(t 0)(d display))(when(> x 69)(d"\n")(set! x 0))(cond[(> t 699)
(d"\n")][(> n 2)(d"|")(p 0(+ 1 x)(+ 1 t)d)][(d"_")(p(+ 1 n)(+ 1 x)(+ 1 t)d)]))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f)
  (let loop ((n 2)   (x 0)   (t 0)  (d display))

    (when (> x 69)  (d "\n")
                    (set! x 0))
    (cond
      [(> t 699)    (d "\n")]

      [(> n 2)      (d "|")
                    (loop    0    (+ 1 x) (+ 1 t) d)]

      [else         (d "_")
                    (loop (+ 1 n) (+ 1 x) (+ 1 t) d)]
      )))
```

Testing:

```
(f)
```

Output:

```
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>89</s> <s>80</s> <s>77</s> <s>76</s> <s>72</s> <s>53</s> <s>47</s> 42 Bytes

```
puts (%w[___]*176*?|)[2..-1].scan(/.{70}/)
```

Demo:

```
>> puts (%w[___]*176*?|)[2..-1].scan(/.{70}/)
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Update: I didn’t see there’s already [an answer with 30 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99044/5144).

Answer (score 1):

### Java 8, 128

This code directly calculates each character and has no imports or dependencies.

Golfed:

```java
()->{String s="";for(int x,y=0;y<10;++y){for(x=0;x<70;++x)s+=((y%2<1&(x+3)%4<1)|(y%2>0&(x+1)%4<1))?"|":"_";s+="\n";}return s;}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
() -> {
  String s = "";
  for (int x, y = 0; y < 10; ++y) {
    for (x = 0; x < 70; ++x)
      s += ((y % 2 < 1 & (x + 3) % 4 < 1) | (y % 2 > 0 & (x + 1) % 4 < 1)) ? "|" : "_";
    s += "\n";
  }
  return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3, 69 bytes

```
(3...702).map{print($0%4<1 ?"|":"_",terminator:($0-2)%70<1 ?"\n":"")}
```

Output after compiling and running:

```
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

[Try online here](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5823a3dea56869580c97182c) (In this tool it run as script so it will produce a warning due the `map` result is unused.

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, <s>117</s> 110 bytes

```clj
(fn[](println(apply str(map #(str(apply str %)"\n")(partition 70(subs(apply str(repeat 175 "_|__"))0 700))))))
```

Basically creates a long string of `"_|__"`s 700 characters long, cuts it every 70 characters, then joins them with newline.

Managed to get rid of the calls to `join`!

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn build-wall []
  (println
    (apply str
      (map #(str (apply str %) "\n")
        (partition 70
          (subs (apply str
                  (repeat 175 "_|__"))
                0 700))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 43

```python
print(("_|__"*17+"_|\n"+"__|_"*17+"_\n")*5)
```

Fixed to be more Trump-like.

Answer (score 1):

### SAS, 68

```
option linesize=70;data;length w$700;w=repeat('_|__',174);put w;run;
```

The 174 is not a typo - in SAS the repeat function rather pedantically returns the original string plus `n` repeats.

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin, 99 bytes

```
fun main(a:Array<String>){"_|__".repeat(999).split(Regex("(?<=\\G.{70})")).take(10).map(::println)}
```

Regex taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3761521/7079453). First ever golf, done in 10 minutes, probably improvable..

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Can you remove some of the spaces? Like `a:Array<String>`?

Comment: How'd I miss that...thanks.

Comment: @mEQ5aNLrK3lqs3kfSa5HbvsTWe0nIu What does your name mean?

Comment: I use random usernames everywhere, I don't like the possibility of somebody googling my nick and finding out everything about my online life.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 54 bytes

```
w=("_|__"):rep(17)print((w.."_|\n__"..w.."\n"):rep(5))
```

No fancy splits for Lua, but it does have an easy repeat.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 46 bytes

```
import textwrap as t;print t.fill('_|__'*175)
```

I was going to do an exec loop similar to @xnor's one alternate solution but he/she got to it before me. I guess I'll just have to let Python do the dirty work for me.

Answer (score 1):

## R, 62 bytes

Don't have the rep to comment, so posting as an answer: @user3297046's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99150/61633) can be golfed-down to 62 bytes:

```
cat(gsub('(.{70})','\\1
',paste(rep('_|__',175),collapse='')))
```

which results in

```
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 56 bytes

Although I know it can be done smaller using wordwrap or string splits, I prefer more hacky solutions.

```
for($i=0;$i<700;$i++){echo($i%70?'':'
').'_|___'[$i%4];}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>61</s> 58 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```c
f(i){for(i=700;i--;i%70|!i||puts(""))printf(L"__|_"+i%4);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPT1tzAwDpTV9c6U9XcoEYxs6amoLSkWENJSVOzoCgzryRNw0cpPr4mXkk7U9VE07r2P1BMITcxM08DaIAGSAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), 69 bytes

Outputs as a list of lines.

```
_=-~(_==_)
__=-~_*-~_*_
_=[('_|__'*__)[:-_],('___|'*__)[:-_]]*-~(_*_)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/3la3TiPe1jZekysexI7XAuF4rnjbaA31@Jr4eHWt@HjNaCvd@FgdoEB8fA1CIFYLpFcrXvP/fwA)**

Alternatively, for 16 more bytes, we can print the wall:

```
_=-~(_==_)
__=-~_*-~_*_
_=(('_|__'*__)[:-_]+"""
"""+('___|'*__)[:-_]+"""
""")*-~(_*_)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYyxCoAgFAB3P8NFfeIPBH5JxEEtBZVBLYL066Zzw8HBwd35mNO@LeHKz5rOWonhtcSIU3RHOiiitYYCRsCNQ2DyWmvV8C1A@Qcn/SW4Wj8)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 83 bytes

```
?-between(0,699,I),(1 is I mod 4->write("|");write("_")),69 is I mod 70,nl,1=0;1=1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/3143KbWkPDU1T8NAx8zSUsdTU0fDUCGzWMFTITc/RcFE1668KLMkVUOpRknTGsqMV9LUBCpGqDI30MnL0TG0NbA2tDXU@/8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), <s>84</s> <s>78</s> <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```
time {append a [expr [incr i]%4-2?"_":"|"];if $i%70<1 {puts $a;unset a}} 700
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHhBoAwFAbQV/lc9TNWYrToQTKZunGpmVrE2rOvc@J6lBLlZCQXAvsNDjO/4cIsfr0gtu6bbqKFBvrIGtlRSa3V2CKFJ96onHn8zREuZ2ilSvkB)

Comment: Interesting trick of `append` and `unset`!

Comment: @sergiol you sure took your time to reply :P also haven't been using tcl lately. idk if i should start using it again

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 70 bytes

```lisp
(dotimes(i 700)(format t"~[|~:;_~]~[
~:;~]"(mod(1- i)4)(mod(1+ i)70)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jJb8kMze1WCNTwdzAQFMjLb8oN7FEoUSpLrqmzso6vi62LpoLyKiLVdLIzU/RMNRVyNQ00YSwtYFscwNNTc3//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
B?³‟‾Ｈ×‾7ｎ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=QiUzRiVCMyV1MjAxRiV1MjAzRSV1RkYyOCVENyV1MjAzRTcldUZGNEU_,v=8)

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
αｎｑ［‟５＊‾7ｍ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUwM0IxJXVGRjRFJXVGRjUxJXVGRjNCJXUyMDFGJXVGRjE1JXVGRjBBJXUyMDNFNyV1RkY0RA__,v=8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 10 bytes

```
‛_|ǏǏ⁺J*₀/
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwi4oCbX3zHj8eP4oG6SirigoAvIiwiIiwiIl0=)

### How?

```
‛_|ǏǏ⁺J*₀/
‛_|         # Push string "_|"
   ǏǏ       # Append its first character twice, yielding "_|__"
     ⁺J*    # Repeat it 175 times
        ₀/  # Split into ten equal parts
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 37 bytes

```
print$_.$/x!(++$i%35)for('_|',__)x175
```

Ungolfed:

```perl
my $i = 0;
print($_, "\n" x !(++$i % 35)) for ('_|', '__') x 175;
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 72 bytes

```
#::((print (replace (repeat "_|__" 175) (regex "(.{70})" "g") "$1\n"))))
```

Sample usage:

```
% wall.lithp
(
    (def x #::((print (replace (repeat "_|__" 175) (regex "(.{70})" "g") "$1\n"))))
    (x)
)
```

Output:

```
$ ./run.js wall.lithp
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 90 bytes

```
@set s=_________________
@for /l %%i in (1,1,5)do @echo _^|%s:_=___^|%&echo __%s:_=_^|__%
```

`|`s cause problems if I want to use them as contents of the variable so it's easiest to stick with them as replace strings.

Answer (score 0):

## BASH, <s>91</s>,34 bytes

```
printf _\|__%.0s {1..175}|fold -70
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, <s>136</s> <s>124</s> <s>120</s> 115 bytes

```
String c(){String r,x=r="";int i=999,q=0;for(;i-->0;x+="_|__");for(;i++<10;r+=x.substring(q,q+=70)+"\n");return r;}
```

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/IyKLYP)

```
class M{
  static String c(){
    String r,
           x = r = "";
    int i = 999,
        q = 0;
    for(; i-- > 0; x += "___|");
    for(; i++ < 10; r+= x.substring(q, q+=70) + "\n");
    return r;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c());
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Comment: Is it possible to use recursion instead of a for-loop here? That could cut down on some amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 30 bytes

```
puts ('_|__'*175).scan /.{70}/
```

Output:

```
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Level River St](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15599/level-river-st)'s [Ruby solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99044) posted 20 hours earlier. :(

Answer (score 0):

### Vim, <s>26</s> 22 strokes

Assume the `q` register to be empty (if not type `qqq`)

```
175i_|__<esc>0qq70li<enter><esc>q8@q
```

Comment: It's `8q` at the end, not `9q`. 9q produces a single underscore on an 11th line.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>101</s> 119 bytes

18 for the import: `java.util.stream.*;`

Lambda that returns the wall. We generate an infinite Stream of brick pieces ('_|__'), limit it to 175, and collect them into a string. We then use replaceAll to swap in a newline every 70 characters.

```
()->Stream.generate(()->"_|__").limit(175).collect(Collectors.joining()).replaceAll("(.{70})","$1\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Gema, 45 characters

```
\A=@subst{<U70>=\$1\\n;@repeat{175;_|__}}@end
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '\A=@subst{<U70>=\$1\\n;@repeat{175;_|__}}@end'
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, 232 bytes

```
brick = ["_","_","_","|"];
brickIndex = 2;
output = "";
for(var y=0;y<10;y++){
    for(var x=0;x<70;x++){
      brickIndex = brickIndex % 4;
      output += brick[brickIndex++];
    }
    output += "\n";
}
console.log(output)
```

Comment: “All solutions to challenges should: (…) Be a serious contender for the winning criteria in use. For example, an entry to a code golf contest needs to be golfed (…)” – [help/on-topic] Please read [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) and/or [Tips for golfing in JavaScript](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) for hints on reducing your code's size.

Answer (score 0):

## jq, 37 characters

(33 characters code + 4 characters command line options)

```
range(10)|.*2|("_|__"*70)[.:.+70]
```

```
range(10)|("_|__"*70)[.*2:.*2+70]
```

```
range(0;20;2)|("_|__"*70)[.:.+70]
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -nr 'range(10)|.*2|("_|__"*70)[.:.+70]'
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

On-line test [code 1](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=range(10)|.*2|(%22_|__%22*70)[.:.%2b70]&j=null), [code 2](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=range(10)|(%22_|__%22*70)[.*2:.*2%2b70]&j=null) and [code 3](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=range(0%3b20%3b2)|("_|__"*70)[.:.%2b70]&j=null) (Passing `-r` through URL is not supported – check Raw Output yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

## sh (via base64 and pigz) 59 bytes

```
echo eNqLr4mPpxxzgQjKMRc5mkZdM+oaAG7xGAs=|base64 -D|pigz -d
```

Answer (score 0):

## [FurryScript](https://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Zzo38/FurryScript), 71 bytes

```
A[ <_|> 17 REP +<___|> +BR +<__> 17 REP +<_|__> +BR ]
<<A><A><A><A><A>>
```

**Explanation:**

```
A[ ... ]            {{ Subroutine called A }}
<_|>                {{ Push string "_|" }}
17 REP              {{ Repeat next command 17 times: }}
+<___|>             {{ Concatenate "___|" }}
+BR                 {{ Concatenate newline }}
+<__>               {{ Concatenate "__" }}
17 REP              {{ Repeat next command 17 times: }}
+<_|__>             {{ Concatenate "_|__" }}
+BR                 {{ Concatenate newline }}
<<A><A><A><A><A>>   {{ Template; result of A, 5 times }}
```

Answer (score 0):

## bash, 35 bytes

```
printf '\e[8;;70t_|__%.0s' {1..175}
```

Must be run in graphical terminal as it sets the size of the window.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.5.2, 44 bytes

`exec("print('_|__'*18);print('___|'*18);"*5)`

This is my first attempted golf, so feel free to leave a suggestion!

[Try it here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python3_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSkN2NHNsVVRuZUk)

Answer (score 0):

## MySQL, <s>196</s> <s>123</s> <s>118</s> 95 bytes

First wall was backwards, removed procedure.

```
set @x:=repeat('_|__',99);select left(repeat(concat(left(@x,70),'\n',mid(@x,3,70),'\n'),9),709)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3 - 41 chars

```
s="_|__"*17
print((s+"_|\n__"+s+"\n")*5)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 54 bytes

```
for i in range(10):print(('_|__'*175)[70*i:70*(i+1)])
```

I know this is longer than other Python 3 solutions, so I post because it is a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 21 bytes

```
`_|__`17:4d;T:vv"^^{{
```

Really wish I could golf it more, will have another go later. It works like so:

```
`_|__`                  % Push the brick string to the stack
      17:4d;            % Copy 17 times
            T:          % 10 times do:
              vv"^^     %   Print without the last two characters
                   {{   %   Shift the string left twice
```

Seeing as there's no online interpreter as of yet, here's what it looks like:

```
$ pushy brickwall.pshy

_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
_|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|__
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
Ωo³‘'╥*'4n
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUwM0E5byVCMyV1MjAxOCUyNyV1MjU2NSolMjc0bg__)

Explanation:

```
Ωo³‘        push "_|__"
    '╥*     multiply the string 175 times
       '4n  split into lines of length 70
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, 15 bytes

```
AÆ70î"_|__"éX*2
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=QcY3MO4iX3xfXyLpWCoy&input=LVI=)

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
Ao@70î"_|__"éX*2

Ao@      range(10).map(X=>...)
70î        Repeat the following string to length 70...
"_|__"éX*2   This string rotated X*2 chars to the right.
         `-R` joins the resulting array with newline
         Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck, 141 bytes

```
+++++[>+++++[>>++++>+++++<<<-]>++>-<<<-]>>>>->+++++[<<.>.>>++++++++[>++>++<<-]>+>+<[<<<<...>.>>>-]<<<<<.>>>>>>[<<<<<...>.>>>>-]<<<<<..<.>>>-]
```

[Try it online !](https://tio.run/##TYtRCoAwDEMPNNoThFxk7EMFQQQ/hJ2/du0U85OEvKz3clx7306zMlQ5LTwLAGkeKZlcMjFAqcm@b47D4FnguxMaDKUhKkMV/@0bFYmaPQ)

My first brainfuck answer !

There is a more aerial and commented version :

```
+++++[>+++++[>>++++>+++++<<<-]>++>-<<<-]>>>>->  value storage
+++++[                                          doing this ↓ 5 times
  <<.>.>                                        first "_|"
  >++++++++[>++>++<<-]>+>+<                     storing 17 two times
    [<<<<...>.>>>-]                             first 17 "|___" batch
    <<<<<.>>>>>>                                new line
    [<<<<<...>.>>>>-]                           second 17 "|___" batch
  <<<<<..<.>>>-                                 last "__" and new line
]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charm](https://github.com/Aearnus/charm), 87 bytes

```
f := " ___| " 18 repeat
s := substring pstring newline
[ f 2 72 s f 0 70 s ] 5 repeat i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILMr9/z9NwcpWQUkhPj6@BkgZWigUpRakJpZwFYPEi0uTikuKMvPSFQqgdF5qeU5mXipXtEKagpGCuZFCMZBhoGBuAGTEKphCdStk/v8PAA)

Charm's `repeat` makes this kind of thing easy, but its syntax prevents very good scores regardless.

Explanation:

```
f := " ___| " 18 repeat " function to push 18 bricks " pop
s := substring pstring newline " we need to get a substring before printing it with a newline at two different points during the program, so we save bytes defining a function for it " pop
[ f 2 72 s f 0 70 s ] 5 repeat i " now we apply our functions, getting two slightly different substrings of the bricks from the f function and printing them, repeating this 5 times "
```

Comment: would it be shorter to get the ascii value of the new line ?

Comment: `10 char p` is longer than `newline`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
⪪×¹⁷⁵_|__⁷⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4ICezRENLw9DcVEdBKb4mPl5JU0fB3EBT8////7plOQA)