# I deserve a castle for it only being Tuesday

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

It is only Tuesday, ugh. I deserve a treat. Golf me a Castle. The Least amount of bytes wins!

Taken no input and output this image exactly:

```
 /\           /\
/  \         /  \
----         ----
|  |^^^^^^^^^|  |
-----------------
|       _       |
|   |  | |  |   |
|      | |      |
```

#### Edit

[Build me a brick wall!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99026/build-me-a-brick-wall)
36 votes versus my -9. Okay.

Comment: shortest code or lowest byte count.?

Comment: Least amount of bytes

Comment: @dylan What's the difference?

Comment: @DrMcMoylex http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/17020/61857

Comment: my post was ironic to the date + was fairly simple. yours seems much more complicated and more diverse which is why i didn't take a stab at it.

Comment: I haven't upvoted or downvoted but there didn't really seem any smart way to do this. "Build me a brick wall" had repeating patterns which you could work with. This doesn't. I did have a go (in Python) but gave up after a while. I didn't see it in the Sandbox otherwise I would have commented there. Sorry to see all of the downvotes. Sandbox rocks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Bubblegum](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 52 bytes

```
00000000: 35c8 3111 c030 1443 b1fd a310 815c 08f5  5.1..0.C.....\..
00000010: 5a22 06df 64b0 263f db0f 7562 367d b831  Z"..d.&?..ub6}.1
00000020: eb50 3726 e4ad 9059 5513 c007 c804 2142  .P7&...YU.....!B
00000030: f441 74fc                                .At.
```

Obligatory Bubblegum answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Swift 3, 200 bytes

```
var z=" /\\ 9/\\\n/  \\ 7/  \\\n-2 7-2\n|  |^7|  |\n-95\n| 5_ 5|\n| 1|  | |  | 1|\n| 4| | 4|",o="",x=""
for c in z.characters{let k="\(c)"
if let b=Int(k){for i in 0...b{o+=x}}else{o+=k
x=k}}
print(o)
```

Basically loop trough the `Characters` of `z` string, if a digit (b) is found then repeat the last character `b+1` times

[Try online here](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5823c9fda56869580c971836)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 130 bytes

```
f=->a,b=' '{a+b*9+a};g=->s{?|+s.center(15)+?|};puts f[' /\\ '],f['/  \\'],f[c=?-*4],f[d='|  |',?^],f[c,?-],g[?_],g[d+' '+d],g['| |']
```

This can probably be golfed down more.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 120 bytes

```js
_=>` /\\44/\\
/8\\36/8\\
173617
|8|38|8|
69
|28_28|
|12|8| |8|12|
|24| |24|`.replace(/\d\d?/g,n=>' -^'[n&3].repeat(n/4))
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

_=>` /\\44/\\
/8\\36/8\\
173617
|8|38|8|
69
|28_28|
|12|8| |8|12|
|24| |24|`.replace(/\d\d?/g,n=>' -^'[n&3].repeat(n/4))

console.log(f())
```