# Rotation invariant fingerprinting

Tags: code-golf, array, hashing, polyomino

Imagine we have some [polyomino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino) and would like to uniquely identify them, however the polyominos can be rotated, so blindly hashing them won't give us the same fingerprint for a piece and a rotation thereof (in general).

For example if we have the L-tetromino

```
x
x
xx
```

we would like it to have the same fingerprint as any of these:

```
         xx
  x       x      xxx
xxx  ,    x  or  x
```

**Note:** We only allow rotations on the plane (ie. they are one-sided polyominos) and therefore the following polyomino would be a different one:

```
 x
 x
xx
```

### Challenge

The task for this challenge is to implement a fingerprinting-function/program which takes an \$m\times n\$ Boolean/\$0,1\$-valued matrix/list of lists/string/.. encoding a polyomino and returns a string - the fingerprint of a polyomino. The fingerprint must be equal for all of the possible rotations (in general 4).

### Input / Output

- \$m \geq 1\$ and \$n \geq 1\$ (ie. no empty polyomino)
- you're guaranteed that \$m,n\$ are as small as possible (ie. all \$0\$ are trimmed to fit \$m\$ and \$n\$
- you're guaranteed that the input is

  - simply connected
  - has no holes
- output must be a string which is the same for each possible rotation of a polyomino

### Examples

**Here are some equivalence classes, for each class the fingerprint must be the same & for any two polyominos from two distinct classes they must differ.**

The rotations of the L-tetromino from the example:

```
[[1,0],[1,0],[1,1]]
[[0,0,1],[1,1,1]]
[[1,1],[0,1],[0,1]]
[[1,1,1],[1,0,0]]
```

The J-tetromino:

```
[[0,1],[0,1],[1,1]]
[[1,1,1],[0,0,1]]
[[1,1],[1,0],[1,0]]
[[1,0,0],[1,1,1]]
```

The unit polyomino:

```
[[1]]
```

A \$5\times 1\$ bar:

```
[[1,1,1,1,1]]
[[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]]
```

A \$2\times 2\$ corner:

```
[[1,1],[1,0]]
[[1,0],[1,1]]
[[0,1],[1,1]]
[[1,1],[0,1]]
```

W-pentomino:

```
[[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[0,1,1]]
[[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,0]]
[[1,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,0,1]]
[[0,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,0]]
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/138217/which-tetromino-is-this).

Comment: If I always output `""` (the empty string), have I satisfied all the requirements?

Comment: @DanielWagner: "[..] *for any two polyominos from two distinct classes* [the fingerprints] *must differ*" - so no, that would be invalid.

Comment: Is outputting *all* possible rotations of an array, consistently sorted valid? [Example](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=NMY9esPx&input=W1swLDEsMV0sWzEsMSwwXSxbMSwwLDBdXQotUQ==)

Comment: @Shaggy: Yes, that would meet all the criteria.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,z=5:z and max(l,f(zip(*l)[::-1],z-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9BCsMgEEX3nmKWWiYQC90IOYm4sKTSBGMkpGC9vDWpSdouOpuv3z@@Gf@c76M7p2Qaq4drq8FibC4ignYtDDpQi4bGztOTZVKIiiuMFWcsmXGCAJ0DKSXHGmuFWfmqdVauFBKZj/myW1tkffpOY4mWrs80FoBSgkAuP3VupoYO2tP54e0NA2OMkGWkvoy0U9@/HMQf0sYplM089uF/sP2CTS8)

Takes the largest of the four rotations in terms of list comparison. Based on [FlipTack's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177665/20260).

The code uses Python 2's ability to compare objects of different types. The base case value of `0` is harmless for `max` because it's smaller than any list. Also, `zip` produces a list of tuples while the input is a list of lists, but tuples are bigger than lists so the input list-of-lists is never a contender. This is why we rotate 5 times rather than 4, so that we get back to a tuplified version of the initial list. (Taking a list of tuples would also work, if that's an allowed form of input.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 63 bytes

```python
def f(m):M=[];exec("m=[*zip(*m[::-1])];M+=m,;"*4);return min(M)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9NDsIgEIX3nIK4gopJia4gPUJPMJmVQqQJtCE1qV4esdLWHzaPGd68bxju47UPx5QuxlLLPFdtA6jNZM5s5xuoHm5glQelDhI56nbfeKF31YnraMZbDNS7wFqebB/pRF2gACBFLWoUWeWsdVaJKAjkay7W1mKZn77doljL1KdbFACiIjSfIbowMssmzgl57dGVPVbUe3TD/MQv4SV6aW6fkH@sLrPSEw)

Finds the rotation with the lexographical minimum, and prints that.

A lambda form comes in at the same byte count:

```python
lambda m,M=[]:exec("m=[*zip(*m[::-1])];M+=m,;"*4)or min(M[-4:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9NDoMgEIX3nIJ0BXZMJHWF4QiegM7CtppiChrjwvbylFrU/rB5zPDmfUN/H6@dO/hGHf2tsqdLRS2USqOsp/rMdlbp5GF6llgtZSqQY1HulYVil@S8G6g1jpU6zSVy34R6osZRrbWADDKEoGLWLKhABKLDNRRra7HMT99uiNY49emGCECUhIbTD8aNrGET54S89mjjHivqPbphfuKX8Bi9NLdPiD9WG1j@CQ)

Comment: Rewriting as a `lambda` can get you to 58. `lambda m,M=[]:exec("m=[*zip(*m[::-1])];M+=m,;"*4)or min(M)`. Works because `exec` always returns `None`.

Comment: @nedla2004 That can only be run once, and then gets dodgy as `M` is already populated...

Comment: @nedla2004 ... but accounting for the problem with `M[-4:]` can get you to the same byte count.

Comment: I see, the test I was using was just checking inputs with the same "hash", so I never ran into that. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ZU$ƬṂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8qVOXYmoc7m/7//x8dbaBjqGMYqxMNJHUMwLQBkI4FAA)

Full program.

Simply generates all possible rotations and picks the lexicographical minimum.

Note that singleton lists aren't wrapped in `[]` in the output. That doesn't matter, since the only case where singleton lists would exist in the input would be a vertical line (including the unit polyomino), which is the same as a horizontal line with the same size (where the ones aren't wrapped). The only case where the outer `[]` will not exist either is the unit polyomino.

Comment: when i read the challenge i knew this would happen :)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 16 bytes

```
{a@*<a:3{+|x}\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHRToMwFH3nK26iyYoyKTO@gCY@G999UBM7dgtkXUtKl7DM@etYKDDYGkqa03PPPfd0u5SZbBoeH9nr3TOLH4/3v/Xpqz41LCaEREATtyMfhhW@Lw0arXaFVF4LEAoUopZkaQ6xp4S6fUY6juX6HURIT7hQf7tUd5Vdj4l6b21EqLNpOR0UBEEE1yvcy8JAqcRhbEBcA5i5sMynOoI1004/iJLJNwzQ@/DnLVb1ClKlJerRW3JOZhh4ltNZcBiDtrBzFH4sS5TmKm/aJzpNYSyc5TVhDi/gex5fBCHzvDBlQgAHrjS0J6zZrhRYBZBptS9hfQCTI2is9sJUwOQGMjQgUGYmB8UBWZo7rtXKMd1CwduSA@yYsVdYl5ga3PR6rrDybj/JTbxg/p/9P7x0ZpIftU1@OCvEd/MP)

min of rotations

`{` `}` function with argument `x`

`{+|x}` rotate, i.e. reverse (`|`) and transpose (`+`)

`3{` `}\` apply 3 times preserving intermediate results; this returns a list of the 4 rotations

`a:` assign to `a`

`<` ascend (compute the sort-ascending permutation)

`*` first

`a@` index `a` with that

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 136 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Data.List
r=reverse;t=transpose;f=flatten
$l=[if((a==b)==(c==d))'x''X'\\a<-f l&b<-f(r(map r l))&c<-f(r(t l))&d<-f(t(r l))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLPb4MgFD7rX8GhWSFxi543bt1hyQ5LdlnijKEWWxoEA892/efnEK3VuhiE73u8H997FJIz1VZ610iOKiZUK6paG0CfsHtVp2jDgD29CwuhoYafuLH8GSgYpmyt3bmkpWQAXIUrSVNRYswo3RJKcUHpjpD1z3r9tf7@Zi@PJZIPW7dhgytWI4MkIQ9FT4AHuw4A9pas/QTm6qBIcggD4BasA6nMgYPRlVA6QscpaJSAvNbyMuBSnHi@veRauY2ZCMFZd7jbCm0Ud9Q5r7kC72CzMDDcNtLn6SrEqtki7Y8rgnwFoVAIMykRxpSSxFklV3s4EDS4RkhpQPjA7KZxEYbmXK2EkPB84IaHwURHJysMgjRNojiLxn@SZZGn4yh2wFM3MvFUPP5v9HDXeWVOUuDW8Z9c8cQ/Wfr3OWe5btWNdHwttbvb55pP4Sbtar@bykT78I3Ru8izNURYjHEaY1HhfSuXeq8N7KNPX8R0MKPSuL@/HE88tn5WwdTjrq9zj9nQ2t/CvZ29bR/f3tvNRbFKFD34cE@q1Kb6Aw)

Includes test verifier.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-g`, 6 bytes

```
4Æ=zÃñ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=NMY9esPx&input=W1swLDEsMV0sWzEsMSwwXSxbMSwwLDBdXQotZ1E=)

```
           :Implicit input of 2d-array U
4Æ         :Map the range [0,4)
   z       :  Rotate U 90 degrees
  =        :  Reassign to U
    Ã      :End map
     ñ     :Sort
           :Implicit output of first element
```

Comment: Is the `-g` flag necessary? Sort should mean that all initial rotations end up with the same list so that full list should work fine as the fingerprint unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @KamilDrakari, you could well be right - like I said, I'm not sure I *fully* understood the challenge. No harm leaving it in, though, it's not costing any bytes.

Comment: @KamilDrakari: It is not necessary, but it's no harm either as it's not counted towards the bytecount.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 16 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Shaggy

```
[:/:~|.@|:^:(<4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8D/aSt@qrkbPocYqzkrDxkTzvyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvkKagrGCkYKKgiFQJwQbKij4Oekp@OiWpJYU5edm5uUrQJSqq8O0GAE1qQAVQ5TDtSTmFOcj60PXBrEJYY8hugJMARjEdAHE0SBogGmPMdRHEHug9H8A)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
0{[:/:~|.@|:^:(<4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8N@gOtpK36quRs@hxirOSsPGRPO/JpeSnoJ6mq2euoKOQq2VQloxF1dqcka@QpqCsYKRgoqCIVAvBBsqKPg56Sn46JaklhTl52bm5StAlKqrw7QYATWpABVDlMO1JOYU5yPrQ9cGsQlhjyG6AkwBGMR0AcTRIGiAaY8x1EcQe6D0fwA)

Returns the first item in the list of the lexicograpically sorted rotations of the polyomino.

### Explanation:

```
            ^:(<4)  - do the verb on the left 4 times, storing all the steps
       |.@|:        - tranpose and reverse
    /:~             - sort up the 4 matrices
  [:                - cap the fork
0{                  - take the first matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>10</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
3FÂø})Σ˜
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@Shaggy*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f2O1w0@EdtZrnFp@e8/9/dLShjkGsDpw0jI0FAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WmR6feWib/eHVlS72SgqP2iYpKNn/N3Y73HR4R63mucWn5/yv1fkfHR1tqGMQqwMnDWNjdRSiow10DIBMsABMyBAsYAAnYYJQdUAdICElJYh2hFpDdLUQs5HMRLgAKmgAcwxEHcRMZKYOFEI1gBSjYGSVaEaj@hLdgQi/wfQj3GIAkUQPIgN4ECBZg6waxceoquEBFwsA).

**Explanation:**

```python
3F  }       # Loop 3 times
  Â         #  Bifurcate (short for Duplicate & Reverse) the top of the stack
            #  (which is the input-matrix implicitly the first iteration)
   ø        #  Transpose: swap rows/columns
     )      # After the loop, wrap everything on the stack in a list
      Σ˜    # Sort this list of matrices by their flattened array (and output implicitly)
```

NOTE: Taking the minimum with `ß` or `W` will implicitly flatten, so will output `0`. And sorting with `{` doesn't seem to work for a list of matrices, which is why I use `Σ˜` instead.

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks! :) In that case the last two bytes can be removed, since the `}` is done implicitly if nothing comes after it.

Comment: Today I learned something about 05AB1E! :) It's the same in Japt.